# ExtJS: Is possible to state if else condition for bind in grid panel?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, extjs, bind, viewmodel

Inside the ViewModel I've defined 2 stores and I'm using a `gridpanel` as view. Is there any chance to state if else condition for `bind` property inside `gridpanel`?

ViewModel:

```
stores: {
        dataStore: {
            model: 'MyApp.first.Model',
            autoLoad: true,
            session: true
        },

        listStore: {
            model: 'MyApp.second.Model',
            autoLoad: true,
            session: true,
        },
```

and on grid panel I want to do this condition;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.base.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    // Currently binds directly to listStore
    bind: '{listStore}',

    // but I'm trying to implement a proper adjustment such as this;
    // bind: function () {
    //     var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    //     if (username === 'sample@adress.com') {'{dataStore}';} else {'{listStore}'}
    // },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use conditional expressions with `bind`, however, you can use `ViewModel`'s formulas to select which store to use with grid. Here is example of such formula:

```
conditionalStore: function (get) {
    var param = get('param');

    if (param === 1) {
        return get('simpsonsStore');
    }
    return get('griffinsStore');
}
```

And here is working fiddle, which you can play with: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eq2

Comment: Worked exact behaviour as I've expected. Thanks a lot for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bindStore`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-bind) method of `grid`.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eq1)**, I have created a demo using `grid`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //defining store 1
        Ext.define('Store1', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.store1',
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: ''
                }
            }
        });

        //defining store 2
        Ext.define('Store2', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.store2',
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data2.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: ''
                }
            }
        });

        //defining view model
        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.myvm',

            stores: {
                gridStore1: {
                    type: 'store1'
                },
                gridStore2: {
                    type: 'store2'
                }
            }
        });

        //creating grid
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'grid',

            title: 'Example of bind the store',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                type: 'myvm'
            },

            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],

            tbar: [{
                text: 'Load Store1',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var grid = this.up('grid');
                    grid.bindStore(grid.getViewModel().getStore('gridStore1'))
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Load Store2',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var grid = this.up('grid');
                    grid.bindStore(grid.getViewModel().getStore('gridStore2'))
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```